# numpy sorting and removing top values

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, sorting

I don't know if there is a name for this algorithm, but basically for a given `y`, I want to find the maximum `x` such that:

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.random.rand(1000, 1)
np.sum(np_array[np_array > x] - x) >= y
```

Of course, a search algo would be to find the top value `n_1`, reduce it to the second largest value, `n_2`. Stop if `n_1 - n-2 > y`; else reduce both `n_1` and `n_2` to `n_3`, stop if `(n_1 - n_3) + (n_2 - n_3) > y` ...

But I feel there must be an algo to generate a sequence of {`x`s} that converges to its true value.

Comment: Cumulative sum on a sorted array?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example to play with? Random arrays are fine.

Comment: sure, np_array = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2]), y = 0.5

Comment: One more question. Is `- x` intentionally inside the sum? Because that actually simplifies things a bit compared to what I was thinking :)

Comment: yeah. so if you picture a sorted (ascending) array as a triangle (x axis being the bottom side, right y axis being the vertical side), it's about finding the horizontal line such that the small triangle above that line has an area of y

Comment: Alright. Enjoy the new answer. I'm pretty sure it works ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use your example from the comments:

```
a = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2])
y = 0.5
```

First let's sort the data in descending order:

```
s = np.sort(a)[::-1]  # 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1,
```

Let's take a look at how the choice of `x` affects the possible values of the sum `r = np.sum(np_array[np_array > x] - x)`:

- If `x ≥ 0.6`, then `r = 0.0 - x` ⇒ `-∞ < r ≤ -0.6`
- If `0.6 > x ≥ 0.5`, then `r = 0.6 - x` ⇒ `0.0 < r ≤ 0.1` (where `0.1 = 0.6 - 0.5 × 1`)
- If `0.5 > x ≥ 0.4`, then `r = 0.6 - x + 0.5 - x = 1.1 - 2 * x` ⇒ `0.1 < r ≤ 0.3` (where `0.3 = 1.1 - 0.4 × 2`)
- If `0.4 > x ≥ 0.3`, then `r = 0.6 - x + 0.5 - x + 0.4 - x = 1.5 - 3 * x` ⇒ `0.3 < r ≤ 0.6` (where `0.6 = 1.5 - 0.3 × 3`)
- If `0.3 > x ≥ 0.2`, then `r = 0.6 - x + 0.5 - x + 0.4 - x + 0.3 - x = 1.8 - 4 * x` ⇒ `0.6 < r ≤ 1.0` (where `1.0 = 1.8 - 0.2 × 4`)
- If `0.2 > x ≥ 0.1`, then `r = 0.6 - x + 0.5 - x + 0.4 - x + 0.3 - x + 0.2 - x + 0.2 - x = 2.2 - 6 * x` ⇒ `1.0 < r ≤ 1.6` (where `1.6 = 2.2 - 0.1 × 6`)
- If `0.1 > x`, then `r = 0.6 - x + 0.5 - x + 0.4 - x + 0.3 - x + 0.2 - x + 0.2 - x + 0.1 - x + 0.1 - x = 2.4 - 8 * x` ⇒ `1.6 < r ≤ ∞`

The range of `r` is continuous except for the portion `a[0] < r ≤ 0.0`. Duplicate elements affect the range of available `r` values for each value in `a`, but otherwise are nothing special. We can remove, but also account for the duplicates by using [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) instead of [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
s, t = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
s, t = s[::-1], t[::-1]
w = np.cumsum(t)
```

If your data can reasonably be expected not to contain duplicates, then use the sorted `s` shown in the beginning, and set `t = np.ones(s.size, dtype=int)` and therefore `w = np.arange(s.size) + 1`.

For `s[i] > x ≥ s[i + 1]`, the bounds of `r` are given by `c[i] - w[i] * s[i] < r ≤ c[i] - w[i] * s[i + 1]`, where

```
c = np.cumsum(s * t)   # You can use just `np.cumsum(s)` if no duplicates
```

So finding where `y` ends up is a matter of placing it between the correct bounds. This can be done with a binary search, e.g., [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
# Left bound. Sum is strictly greater than this
bounds = c - w * s
i = np.searchsorted(bounds[1:], y, 'right')
```

The first element of `bounds` is always `0.0`, and the resulting index `i` will point to the upper bound. By truncating off the first element, we shift the result to the lower bound, and ignore the zero.

The solution is found by solving for the location of `x` in the selected bin:

```
y = c[i] - w[i] * x
```

So you have:

```
x = (c[i] - y) / w[i]
```

You can write a function:

```
def dm(a, y, duplicates=False):
    if duplicates:
        s, t = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
        s, t = s[::-1], t[::-1]
        w = np.cumsum(t)
        c = np.cumsum(s * t)
        i = np.searchsorted((c - w * s)[1:], y, 'right')
        x = (c[i] - y) / w[i]
    else:
        s = np.sort(a)[::-1]
        c = np.cumsum(s)
        i = np.searchsorted((c - s)[1:], y, 'right')
        x = (c[i] - y) / (i + 1)
    return x
```

This does not handle the case where `y < 0`, but it does allow you to enter many `y` values simultaneously, since `searchsorted` is pretty well vectorized.

Here is a usage sample:

```
>>> dm(a, 0.5, True)
Out[247]: 0.3333333333333333

>>> dm(a, 0.6, True)
0.3

>>> dm(a, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], True)
array([0.5       , 0.45      , 0.4       , 0.36666667, 0.33333333])
```

As for whether this algorithm has a name: I am not aware of any. Since I wrote this, I feel that "discrete madness" is an appropriate name. Slips off the tongue nicely too: "Ah yes, I computed the threshold using discrete madness".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at them. I have to say this is more complicated than I thought. As you demonstrated, there is a one-to-one and monotonic mapping between r and x, so I thought there is some convergence can be applied here to find x

Comment: @ian_chan. As the final function shows, it's not that much more complicated than the original answer. Really, most of the hairy stuff is for dealing with duplicates. Since your real data likely won't have any, take a look at the `else` branch

Answer (score 1):

**This is an answer to the original question, where we find the maximum `x` s.t. `np.sum(np_array[np_array > x]) >= y`:**

You can accomplish this with sorting and cumulative sum:

```
s = np.sort(np_array)[::-1]
c = np.cumsum(s)
i = np.argmax(c > y)

result = s[i]
```

`s` is the candidates for `x` in descending order. Comparing the cumulative sum `c` to `y` tells you exactly where the sum will exceed `y`. `np.argmax` returns the index of the first place that happens. The result is that index extracted from `s`.

This computation in numpy is slower than it needs to be because we can short circuit the sum immediately without computing a separate mask. The complexity is the same, however. You could speed up the following with numba or cython:

```
s = np.sort(np_array)[::-1]
c = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    c += s[i]
    if c > y:
        break
result = s[i]
```

Comment: sorry there is a typo, it should be: np.sum(np_array[np_array > x] - x) >= y

Comment: i am not summing over values in np_array, but sum over the amount that is more than x

Comment: @ian_chan. I got that part. When you sort the array, you can just sum the prefix to get that.

Comment: but the prefix is not constant, it depends on s[i]. In the search algo I described, we sort array, n_1 being the biggest number. Then if x = n_2,  np.sum(np_array[np_array > x] - x) = n_1 - n_2; if x = n_3, np.sum(np_array[np_array > x] - x) = (n_1 - n_3) + (n_2 - n_3)... so i dont know how to change the "c += s[i]" step in your algo to accommodate this

Comment: @ian_chan. Must `x` be an element of `np_array`?

Comment: no, it doesnt have to be. it can be any real number that makes the two sides equal

Comment: @ian_chan. Hang on. I'm going to update momentarily. Will post another answer. The algo is pretty similar actually.